# console error Cannot destructure property 'top' of 'el.position(...)' as it is undefined. wordpress jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So I am working on a wordpress site I am not familiar with. I get the following error in the console:

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:formatted:1504 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'top' of 'el.position(...)' as it is undefined.
    at doDotsCalculations (main.js?ver=20190317:6)
    at setOwlDotsPosition (main.js?ver=20190317:5)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js?ver=20190317:5)
    at e (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:formatted:1422)
    at t (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:formatted:1433)
```

I am not entirely sure but this is what i got in main.js and where the error originated from. Any help is much appriciated. I cant see any visual errors in the site but it is adapted for screenreaders and other stuff i cant check for.

```
    $(function() {
        if ($.fn.multiscroll !== undefined) {
            $('#multiscroll').multiscroll({
                verticalCentered: true,
                anchors: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'],
                menu: '#msmenu',
                navigation: false,
                css3: true,
                navigationTooltips: ['First', 'Two', 'Three'],
                responsiveWidth: 992,
                responsiveExpand: true,
                loopBottom: false,
                loopTop: false,
                onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {},
                afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {},
                afterRender: function() {}
            });
        }
        if ($.fn.fullpage !== undefined) {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: [],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage'],
                menu: '#fpsmenu',
                responsiveExpand: true,
                responsiveWidth: 1400,
                continuousVertical: true,
                navigation: false,
                verticalCentered: false
            });
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
        }
        $(".owl-carousel").on("initialized.owl.carousel", ()=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                $(".owl-item.active .owl-slide-animated").addClass("is-transitioned");
                $("section").show();
            }
            , 200);
        }
        );
        const $owlCarousel = $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            navText: ['<svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>', '<svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>']
        });
        $owlCarousel.on("changed.owl.carousel", e=>{
            $(".owl-slide-animated").removeClass("is-transitioned");
            const $currentOwlItem = $(".owl-item").eq(e.item.index);
            $currentOwlItem.find(".owl-slide-animated").addClass("is-transitioned");
            const $target = $currentOwlItem.find(".owl-slide-text");
            doDotsCalculations($target);
        }
        );
        $owlCarousel.on("resize.owl.carousel", ()=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                setOwlDotsPosition();
            }
            , 50);
        }
        );
        setOwlDotsPosition();
        function setOwlDotsPosition() {
            const $target = $(".owl-item.active .owl-slide-text");
            doDotsCalculations($target);
        }
        function doDotsCalculations(el) {
            const height = el.height();
            const {top, left} = el.position();
            const res = height + top + 20;
            $(".owl-carousel .owl-dots").css({
                top: `${res}px`,
                left: `${left}px`
            });
        }
        $(".carousel .carousel-item").first().addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: Can you please check what does $(".owl-carousel .owl-dots").length return?

Comment: it returns zero, sorry 23 when i removed the $

Comment: so there is no element matching that criteria in your DOM, check if correct classes of the element and update $(".owl-carousel .owl-dots") this

Comment: what do you mean remove the '$'? Is it just (".owl-carousel .owl-dots").length gives you 23 ?

Comment: yea , sorry just an amatuer at this.

Comment: `(".owl-carousel .owl-dots").length` gives you the `length` of the string, which is indeed *23*. Not really what you are looking for tho.

Comment: Yea the problem only arises on pages that doesnt have the owl carousell , the frontpage does not give the error but all the other pages do. ettgottliv.com is the page if it helps. https://ettgottliv.com/blogg/ gives the error

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in `doDotsCalculations`?, I also didn't find any element in the DOM with class `owl-item` and `owl-slide-text` and that's the reason when you call `const $target = $(".owl-item.active .owl-slide-text"); doDotsCalculations($target);` it is passing undefined object and you are seeing the error in console when you try to access position of undefined object `el.position();`.

Comment: Not my code, I just trying to fix all the errors, this is one of the last ones left

Comment: I assume that the owl script is loaded unnecessary on the page?

Comment: I'm not, but you can remove that code if it is not needed @Andoriod

Answer (score 0):

You encountered this error because the `element` or some of its properties are `undefined`. Add a check to ensure that `el` is available before trying to access its `top` and `left` positions.

```
function doDotsCalculations(el) {
  if (el) {
    const height = el.height();
    const {top, left} = el.position();
    const res = height + top + 20;
    $(".owl-carousel .owl-dots").css({
      top: `${res}px`,
      eft: `${left}px`
    });
  }
  return null;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Remove the code from pages that are not using the Carousell to eliminate the `error` that you are facing. Pages that are not using it will most certainly not be able to locate the `css` classes `.owl-item.active .owl-slide-text"`, which do not contain `top` and `left` values since the `css` classes are not in the `DOM`.

Comment: `height` returns a value but when you try to destructure `top` and `left`, it fails?

Comment: please explain like im five, top gives the error " Cannot destructure property 'top' of 'el.position(...)' as it is undefined."

Comment: It means that `position()` itself returns undefined, which means the element is hidden or not in the `DOM`.

Comment: in firefox it says Uncaught TypeError: el.position() is undefined
    doDotsCalculations https://ettgottliv.com/wp-content/themes/ettgottliv/js/main.js?ver=20190317:6
    setOwlDotsPosition https://ettgottliv.com/wp-content/themes/ettgottliv/js/main.js?ver=20190317:5
    <anonymous> https://ettgottliv.com/wp-content/themes/ettgottliv/js/main.js?ver=20190317:5 Perhaps do the check earlier?

Comment: so unload the script for owl carausell completely from the pages that dont need it?

Comment: What are the values of `height` and `el` in `doDotsCalculations`()?

Comment: Add `console.log(el)` and `console.log(height)` inside the `if (el)` block and check those 2 values.

Comment: on the frontpage that uses the carousell i get `code` el
main.js?ver=20190317:189 S.fn.init [div.owl-slide-text, prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]0: div.owl-slide-textlength: 1prevObject: S.fn.init [document]__proto__: Object(0)
main.js?ver=20190317:190 height
main.js?ver=20190317:191 424 `code` just the error message on the pages that dont use owl

Comment: Yes, remove the carousell for the pages that do not use the plugin because the `el` will not be found on those positions, and therefore `top` and `left` will be undefined. I have also updated my answer.